# every point on boundary of region of convergence is singular

Tags: complex-analysis, circles

I am given the following function:

$$f(z)=1+z^2+z^4+z^8+z^{16}+ \cdots$$

and shall show that it is holomorphic in the unit disc, that $f\to\infty$ as $z\to e^{2i\pi/2^n}$, and that every point on the circle $|z|=1$ is singular. I struggle with the last part. It seems intuitive, since we are summing up different points on the circle that seem not to have any structure, but how can I show this?

thank you very much,

-m.p.

Comment: The identity $f(z^2)=f(z)-z^2$ might help.

Comment: For an easy idea of some of what is going wrong, check what happens at (1,0) and (-1,0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$ as $z\rightarrow 1^-$. So $z=1$ is a singularity.

Since $f(z)=z^2+f(z^2)$ we have that if $z^2\rightarrow 1^-$ then $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$. So $z$ such that $z^2=1$ are singularities.

We may write $f(z)=z^2+z^4+f(z^4)$ so if $z^4\rightarrow 1^-$ then $f(z)\rightarrow\infty$.

Continuing in this way we see that for any $n$, any $z$ such that $z^{2^n}=1$ is a singularity of $f(z)$. Such $z$ are dense in the unit circle.

Comment: that helps. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The second part helps answer the last part. It implies (with a little tweaking) that every point on the circle is a limit point of points where $f$ blows up.

Comment: thanks for this finishing.